# Do not want to instantiate objects in php classes

Tags: php, oop, static

Can I have static classes in PHP ?
Actually I dont want to instantiate my class, so is there a possible way of doing it like we have in Java and C# ?

Comment: Yes. But: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/). Have you RTFM?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot declare a class to be static in PHP, at least I am not aware of that.  But, you can declare the functions in the class static.

You can declare the constructor to be private which will prevent the class from getting instantiated, and to also prevent this class from being inherited declare the class as final.

```
final class MyClass
  private function __construct() {
    // Cannot instantiate this class
  }

  public static function myStaticFunction() {
    // static function
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, declare this class abstract. You will able to use static methods, but not instantiate.
And never show this code to any programmer who run faster than you.

Comment: Nothing wrong with abstract classes. But static methods are against OOP.

Comment: @OZ_ Static methods aren't against OOP per se, they're a useful part of it. But if you're exclusively using static methods without ever instantiating an object you're not practicing OOP.